# Limitation through the complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, probability-limit-theorems

Problem: Prove that
$$
  \lim_{L \to \infty} \int_{L}^{L-i t} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{z^2}{2}  } \mathrm{d} z =0,
$$
where $z$ is a complex number, $L$ is a non-negative real number.

P/S: I am solving a problem that I thing I need to have this result to attain the final result of the problem. So, I wonder that this limitation is equal to 0 or not?

Answer (score 1):

Let $0\le u\le t$. Then we have

$$
\Re[(L-iu)^2]=\Re[L^2-2iuL-u^2]=L^2-u^2
$$

Consequently, we have
$$
\left|\int_L^{L-it}{1\over\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-{z^2\over2}}\mathrm dz\right|\le{t\over\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{{t^2-L^2\over2}}=O(e^{-L^2/2})\to0
$$
as $L\to+\infty$.

Comment: May I ask you a question? In the inequality, did you use the Taylor expansion to obtain it right?

Comment: Taylor expansion is not needed. It suffices to note that $|e^z|=e^{\Re(z)}$.